# Remove "chapter" keyword from header

Tags: header-footer, chapters, fancyhdr

The current code for my latex document is this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,notitlepage]{report}

\usepackage{lipsum}  

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[C]{\nouppercase{\textit \leftmark}}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}

\thispagestyle{plain}
\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table of Contents}
\thispagestyle{plain}

\newpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{One}
\lipsum[2-5]


\end{document}
```

I want to remove the "Chapter 1." keyword from my header "Chapter 1. One" and I want it like this: "1-One". How to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can redefine `\chaptermark` as in

```
\renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{\markboth{\thechapter\,--\,#1}{}}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,notitlepage]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}     
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[C]{\nouppercase{\textit{\leftmark}}}
\renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{\markboth{\thechapter\,--\,#1}{}}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}

\thispagestyle{plain}
\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table of Contents}
\thispagestyle{plain}

\newpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{One}
\lipsum[2-5]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to `fancyhdr` you can use [`scrlayer-scrpage`](https://ctan.org/pkg/scrlayer-scrpage):

```
\documentclass[12pt,notitlepage]{report}

\usepackage{lipsum}  

\usepackage[pagestyleset=KOMA-Script,headsepline,automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\itshape}% use italic instead of slanted page header
\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{\thechapter--}% Use "1–" instead of "Chapter 1 " in the chapter mark
\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}

\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table of Contents}% Has to be at the begin of
                                % the first ToC page (before \tableofcontents)
\tableofcontents

\cleardoublepage% if twoside next odd page

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{One}
\lipsum[2-5]

\end{document}
```

[image: Using scrlayer-scrpage]

Note: I've also removed strange `\thispagestyle{plain}` commands and moved the `\addcontentsline` command. In you example, it would add the last page of the table of contents to the table of contents, which wouldn't make sense.

As an alternative you could use package [`tocbibind`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tocbibind).

However, I would recommend not to add an entry for the table of contents  into the table of contents. Mostly this doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 2):

A simple possibility is to load `titleps`, which comes with `titlesec` but can be used independently. No fiddling with marks (unless you want to…). Just `\chaptertitle`, `\sectiontitle`, &c.).

```
\documentclass[12pt,notitlepage]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titleps}

\newpagestyle{mypagestyle}{%
\headrule
\sethead{}{\textit{\thechapter.\,–\,\chaptertitle}}{}
\setfoot{}{\thepage}{}
}%

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}

\thispagestyle{plain}
\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table of Contents}

\newpage

\pagestyle{mypagestyle}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{One}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]