# Top Header Page Fancy

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, geometry

I am putting a top header in my thesis and have obtained this results:

[image]

I don’t like the repetition of the world “chapter” and I don’t understand why the width of the line is larger than the text width.

Here is my preamble:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,openright,fleqn,twoside]{report}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{linktocpage}
\usepackage[noadjust]{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}            
\usepackage{enumerate}  
\usepackage{rotating}  
\usepackage[scriptsize]{caption} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[EL]{\nouppercase\leftmark}
\fancyhead[OR]{\nouppercase\rightmark}
\fancyhead[ER,OL]{\thepage}

%\setlength{\paperwidth}{16cm}
%\setlength{\paperheight}{24cm}
%\setlength{\oddsidemargin} {2. cm}
%\setlength{\evensidemargin} {2. cm}
%\addtolength{\oddsidemargin} {-0.4 cm}
%\addtolength{\evensidemargin} {-0.4 cm}
\linespread{1.1}
\usepackage[paperwidth=16cm,paperheight=24cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\newcommand{\p}{\partial}   
\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\bold {#1} }
\newcommand{\aver}[1]{\left\langle {#1} \right\rangle}
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\lVert#1\right\rVert}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
```

Every chapter which is included in an external file starts with these lines:

```
\chapter{Introduction}
\label{capitolo1}
\pagestyle{fancy}
```

Comment: Please ask always one question per question. The first one (remove of "chapter") is a duplicate of: [Remove “chapter” keyword from header](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/268394/remove-chapter-keyword-from-header). The second (width of heading) is a duplicate of: [Problem with the header/ footer width](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40183/problem-with-the-header-footer-width)

Answer (score 1):

The line is too long because you are changing the page geometry after you load `fancyhdr`. To remove "Chapter" from the title, you could change the definition of `\chaptermark` (thanks to Schweinebacke for [his comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/403724/top-header-page-fancy/403725?noredirect=1#comment1005886_403725)).

Off-topic:

- `hyperref` should be loaded as one of the last packages
- your `\headheight` is too small, as a warning tells you, it should be at least `13.59pt`

---

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,openright,fleqn,twoside]{report}

\usepackage[paperwidth=16cm,paperheight=24cm,headheight=13.6pt]{geometry}% -< before fancyhdr

\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[EL]{\nouppercase\leftmark}
\fancyhead[OR]{\nouppercase\rightmark}
\fancyhead[ER,OL]{\thepage}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
 \markboth{\thechapter.\ #1}{}}

\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{lipsum}% hust for this example

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Setting `\chaptername` to empty does not remove the space between `\chaptername` and `\thechapter`. Maybe redefinition of `\chaptermark` would be better: → https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/268394/remove-chapter-keyword-from-header

Comment: BTW: `geometry` has an option `headheight`.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's simpler with `titleps`, which comes with `titlesec`, but can be used independently. We don't have to change chaptername to none (which can have unwanted side-effects):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,openright,fleqn,twoside]{report}

\usepackage[paperwidth=16cm,paperheight=24cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{titleps}
\newpagestyle{mystyle}{%
\headrule%
\sethead[\bfseries\thepage][][\bfseries\thechapter.~\chaptertitle]{\bfseries\thechapter. ~\chaptertitle}{}{\bfseries\thepage}
\setfoot{}{}{}
}%

\usepackage{lipsum}%

\pagestyle{mystyle}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's right. I'll do it in a moment. Thanks for pointing me to this thread!